# odoo 10 - "Overwriting" Javascript Code from old module

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to make changes to some javascript in a new module, but I can't for the life of me understand what I'm doing incorrectly.

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/hr_attendance/static/src/js/kiosk_confirm.js

This is the code I'm trying to change, specifically this snippet:

```
this.next_action = 'hr_attendance.hr_attendance_action_kiosk_mode';
```

And this is the code I've gotten so far, what I think is the closest iteration to what would be correct:

```
odoo.define('tko_hr_attendance.script', function(require) {
"use strict";

var core = require('web.core');
var Model = require('web.Model');
var Widget = require('web.Widget');

var QWeb = core.qweb;
var _t = core._t;


instance.web.WebClient.include({


    init: function (parent, action) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.next_action = 'mail.mail_channel_action_client_chat';
        return this._super();
        },
    });
});
```

And this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="assets_backend_custom_id" name="tko_hr_attendance assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/tko_hr_attendance/static/src/js/script.js"></script>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>
```

I've tried following examples from odoo 8, 9 and 10, but I don't think they apply to the specific change I'm trying to make, or I either don't understand fully how the changes are applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the init First you need to get the class and you see in last code they put here

```
   core.action_registry.add('hr_attendance_kiosk_confirm', KioskConfirm);
```

They add it to action_registry you shoud get using the same key.

```
            var  KioskConfirm = core.action_registry.get('hr_attendance_kiosk_confirm');
```

Then use include to override the init method but you should always call super in most cases.

```
       KioskConfirm.include({
                       init : function (){
                              this._super.applay(this, arguments)
                               //.your code here 
                      }
         });
```

To understand javascript well read odoo tutorial building extension interface after one day you will get a very good idea how to do it

Comment: This worked wonders! Thank you a lot, will definitely check the building extension interface tutorial as well :)

Comment: after reading that toturial you will find out that updating odoo widgets it's not that hard at all

Comment: hello can you also share how to add value on the event:{}